# visual studio 2015 update 1 Oracle ADO.NET provider is either not registered, or could not be loaded

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I'm developing an application using Visual Studio 2015 and Framework version 4.6 with Entity Framewrok 6 and Oracle Database.
Every thing was working fine until today after installing the visual Studio 2015 update 1. I couldn't build the application and I'm getting the following Error Message:

> ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client'
>   is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or
>   could not be loaded.

I tried restoring packages, removing the Oracle packages (DataAccess and EntitFrameWork) and adding them again with no success.
I also found [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3544592?start=0&tstart=0) slightly similar issue in Oracle community but the guy had to uninstall Visual Studio to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.expertdebugger.com/2015/12/08/solving-the-oracle-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-package-did-not-load-correctly-error-createinstance-failed-for-package-oracle-developer-tools-for-visual-studiocould-not-load-file-or-assembly/) post with a solution to my problem:
http://www.expertdebugger.com/2015/12/08/solving-the-oracle-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-package-did-not-load-correctly-error-createinstance-failed-for-package-oracle-developer-tools-for-visual-studiocould-not-load-file-or-assembly/

Comment: Link is now broken. Are you able to explain the solution here?

Comment: @JTech this is sad. it was a good detailed post. anyway, basically I had to:
1. Remove package EntityFramework
2. Remove package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework
3. Remove package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
4. Uninstall Oracle Tools For Visual Studio
5. Restart
6. Install Oracle Tools For Visual Studio
7. Add package EntityFramework
8. Add package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework
9. Add package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess